# How to get document with a specific collection of array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a documents that has specific users in its users array

That is

```
  Schema.books({
    users:[ { type: mongoose.Schema.types.objectId, ref:'users' } ]
  })
```

No am trying to get  book documents with a specific number of users let's say two users.

I did try this

```
Let usersId = [ user1, user2 ]

Book.find().where(users).in(usersId)
```

But instead I get an array of all the user1 is a member of I am totally lost on what to do I really  need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the [`$and` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/). Without the $and operator you are querying for books that has userId1 or userId2

```
Book.find({
  $and: [{ users: userId1 }, { users: userId2 }]
});
```

If your `userId` loop is large or not fixed you can do something like this:

```
Book.find({
  $and: userIds.map(v => ({users:v}))
});
```